# use navigate method anywhere

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a component that not assign in `StackNavigator`. However I still want to use `navigate` method from `react-navigation`. Is that possible ?

For example:

**manage.js**

```
export const mainStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen},
  Content: { screen: ContentScreen },
});
```

**OtherContent.js**

```
class OtherContent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    _MoveToScreen = () =>{
        //try to open ContentScreen from here
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        navigate('ContentScreen');
    }

}
```

I want to use `navigate` in `OtherContent` component. How can I pass the `navigation` props to the component.

Answer (score 0):

Use redux and put it in the state, then u can call it from there i think

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `navigation` from parent as props or use [`withNavigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/views/with-navigation) Higher Order Component by `react-navigation`

Example 1:

```
<OtherContent navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

Example 2:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class OtherContent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    _MoveToScreen = () =>{
        //try to open ContentScreen from here
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        navigate('ContentScreen');
    }
    // ...
}

const OtherContentWithNavigation = withNavigation(OtherContent);
```

;